# Google Earth Engine - Generating Stratified Sample

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to make random forest classification on Sentinel-2 composites to extract crop types. The first part of the script provided below (dealing with the pre-processing of Sentinel-2 data) works just fine.

The problem arises when I try to generate stratified random sample to use as training pixels. For the stratification I used a tiff file uploaded in Assets (the variable named "training_image"). The file is in UTM projection and no data value 0 is used as a mask. The Sentinel-2 composite images also have mask (of clouds and of non-agricultural land). 
I would like to have 1000 points per class (23 classes) but I know that so many points may cause memory problems in GEE. So I tried with just 5 points per class. Nevertheless, I get "Computation time out" error.
Here is the script:

```
// Define periods of analysis
var startdate1 = '2017-10-01';
var enddate1 = '2017-11-30';

var startdate2 = '2018-04-01';
var enddate2 = '2018-05-31';

var startdate3 = '2018-06-01';
var enddate3 = '2018-07-31';

// Define geograpic domain
var geometry = bg_border.geometry();

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Preprocess Sentinel-2 data
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// cloud function to remove clouds
 function maskS2clouds(image){
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

//////////////////PERIOD1-OCT-NOV 2017////////////////////////////////////

// filter Sentinel-2 data
var Sentinel2_period1 = S2.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate(startdate1, enddate1)
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10));
// remove the clouds
var S2_nocloud_period1 = Sentinel2_period1.map(maskS2clouds);
// take the median
var st2median_period1 = S2_nocloud_period1.median();
// select only bands B2-B8, B11 and B12
var S2_period1 = st2median_period1.select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12');


//////////////////PERIOD2-APR-MAY 2018////////////////////////////////////

// filter Sentinel-2 data
var Sentinel2_period2 = S2.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate(startdate2, enddate2)
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10));
// remove the clouds
var S2_nocloud_period2 = Sentinel2_period2.map(maskS2clouds);
// take the median
var st2median_period2 = S2_nocloud_period2.median();
// select only bands B2-B8, B11 and B12
var S2_period2 = st2median_period2.select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12')

//////////////////PERIOD3-JUN-JUL 2018////////////////////////////////////

// filter Sentinel-2 data
var Sentinel2_period3 = S2.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate(startdate3, enddate3)
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10));
// remove the clouds
var S2_nocloud_period3 = Sentinel2_period3.map(maskS2clouds);
// take the median
var st2median_period3 = S2_nocloud_period3.median();
// select only bands B2-B8, B11 and B12
var S2_period3 = st2median_period3.select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12');

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Combine the bands from the three periods
// into one image and clip over geometry
var input_img_S2 = S2_period1.addBands([S2_period2, S2_period3])
                .rename(['P1_B2', 'P1_B3', 'P1_B4', 'P1_B5', 'P1_B6', 'P1_B7', 'P1_B8', 'P1_B11',
                'P1_B12', 'P2_B2', 'P2_B3', 'P2_B4', 'P2_B5', 'P2_B6', 'P2_B7', 'P2_B8', 'P2_B11',
                'P2_B12', 'P3_B2', 'P3_B3', 'P3_B4', 'P3_B5', 'P3_B6', 'P3_B7', 'P3_B8', 'P3_B11',
                'P3_B12'])
                .clip(geometry);


//Update mask - agricultural land only
var input_img_S2m = input_img_S2.updateMask(agri_land_image);

// Add to the map
var visParams = {bands: ['P1_B8', 'P2_B8', 'P3_B8'], max: 0.5};
Map.addLayer(input_img_S2m, visParams, 'Sentinel-2 data', false);


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Now the real classification
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var palette = ["#3ccf97", "#82a7eb", "#b7ea3f", "#ad47dc", "#efa34d", "#4121e0",
               "#c668cb", "#c7ce44", "#2fa5ee", "#73cdc1", "#ca6c9e", "#767ed3",
               "#dc0f0f", "#d47890", "#de4913", "#de4913", "#5bca45", "#e1c86e",
               "#33e642", "#8f62c9", "#a1ef64", "#ef1ec2", "#25d3ed"];


Map.addLayer(training_image, {min: 1, max: 23, palette: palette}, 'training image', false);

var samples = input_img_S2m.addBands(training_image).stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 5, 
  classBand: "b1", 
  scale: 20,
  projection: "EPSG:32635", 
  tileScale: 4,
  geometries: true,
});
print(samples);
```

What can be the reason for this error message?
Here is a link to the script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1cb0374fbca783e90cd115983c9107f8

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the `clip()`, don't use it.  If you don't care about projection, don't specify it.  If you don't receive the 'User memory limit exceeded' error, don't specify `tileScale`.  Even with all those changes, it wouldn't be surprising to see a time out, which will be thrown by the code editor after five minutes if your computation isn't done.  You should `Export` the result, as discussed in [this doc](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/debugging#use-export).

Comment: I specified the projection (which is the projection of the class raster) because I thought this is important to get the accurate class for each generated point. I do not know really if I need it. Thanks for pointing out the export option.